# Razor framework formatting difficulty

Tags: razor

I work in MacOS Ventura 13.3.1 with VS Code 17.5.3 (build 15) and I am working on an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC web application.

I am trying to make the app into a webpage for my personal project.

The part I am struggling on is making a dark mode of the webpage. I want the background to be a darker color with white text.

When I apply the code to do this, part of the page remains default background and text color while the rest changes to the expected dark background with white text.

I've spent a long time guessing and checking on how to get the entire page uniform but I can't figure out the magic place I need to insert the code within the template I started with to get a uniform page (it has complex sectioning in the header and footer portions of the page). I like the layout template and want to use it so I would like help understanding how to apply this modification to the existing framework.

I'm working in the `_Layout.cshtml` file of the template that loads when you follow the instructions to create a ASP.NET Core 7 MVC web application. My understanding is that this file applies the link header and footer and basic webpage settings to the entire collection of the pages when you run the debugger and see the page hosted in testing.

The code snippet that applies my preferred settings is

```
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-secondary text-white">
</div>
```

I don't understand how to apply correctly in here so that the whole page will be uniform:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
            <title>@ViewData["Title"] - secret</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Tpåwßƒ.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
 </head>
        <body>
                <header>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
                            
                                <p style="background-color:black;color:white;">secret</p>
                                
                        </a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">secret</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">secret</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Patch">secret</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Hat">secret</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Ashirt">secret</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Bshirt">secret</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Rank">secret</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="VRPortfolio">secret</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="IRLPortfolio">secret</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">secret</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </nav>
            </header>
            <div class="container">
                <main role="main" class="pb-3">
                    @RenderBody()
                </main>
            </div>

            <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
                <div class="container">
                    &copy; 2023 - secret - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">secret</a> - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">巴bøøK</a> - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">secret</a> - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">secret</a> - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">secret</a> - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">secret</a> - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">secret</a> - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">secret</a> - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">secret</a> - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">secret</a> - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">secret</a> - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">secret</a>
                </div>

            </footer>
            <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
            <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
            @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
        </body>
</html>
    </div>
```

When I do it there are white spots that I can't get rid of with several days of testing.

Note: I was able to create a uniform dark mode application but lost the progress so I know it is possible. I appreciate the help as I am fed up at this point because of the amount of wasted time.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a slightly different way to implement dark mode?

Since you are keen to implement the dark mode using `_Layout` I would suggest switching the stylesheet depending on the mode. For instance, if the user switches to light mode the stylesheet would go from:

### First Method - Toggle Stylesheet

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Tpåwßƒ.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

to

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Tpåwßƒ.dark.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

this way you are avoiding adding classes for each element and avoid styles nesting.

in your case, the code would be something like this in the `<head></head>`

```
<head>
   @if(condition) // depends on the way you're getting the user mode selection
   {
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Tpåwßƒ.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
   }
   else 
   {
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Tpåwßƒ.dark.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
   }
</head>
```

Another way is to use a `color-scheme` meta element.

### Second Method - Using color-scheme meta element

First, you have to add the following meta element in the `<head></head>`:

```
<head>
    @if(condition) // depends on the way you're getting the user mode selection
    {
       <!--Specify the content as either dark or light-->
       <meta name="color-scheme" content="dark">
    }
    else 
    {
       <meta name="color-scheme" content="light">
    }
</head>
```

and in your stylesheet, you will detect the preferred user color scheme:

```css
:root {
   /* you can set up the color scheme on the root level too  */
   color-scheme: dark;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme) {
   /* this is just an example */
   h1 {
      color: black;
   }
}
```

Both methods are great but it all depends on you and how would you approach them.

Also, if you want to persist with the user selection I would suggest using local storage:

Read more in Mozilla docs: [localStorage property docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)